# concatAll on a Ruby tree

Tags: ruby, string, tree

I have two classes Leaf & BinaryNode 
  Leaf contains one field that is a string
  BinaryNode contains two children of which both are either a Leaf or a BinaryNode

I am trying to write a concatAll method that will return a string of all the words in the tree from left to right...

The following is what I have so far, but it is only returning the last string it finds not the  whole string that has been built... how come?

```
def concatAll
 final = ""

 if @lchild.respond_to?('string')   
   final += @lchild.to_s
 else
   @lchild.concatAll unless @lchild.nil?
 end

 if @rchild.respond_to?('string')   
   final +=  @rchild.to_s
 else
   @rchild.concatAll unless @rchild.nil?
 end
end
```

Comment: I think it's quite odd that you're asking if a node responds to `string` before calling `to_s` on it. Then again, I haven't seen the rest of your code.

Comment: yeah, sorry I should have mentioned that. 'string' is just the an accessor method of the Leaf classes string. So I am asking the child if it is a Leaf essentially.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can create a `leaf?` method that returns true/false. This would make the code very clear.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a method is the value of the last expression executed. Without an explicit return value, you're just getting the last string found.

You can simply add one line before the `end`:

```
  final
end
```

and that would return the value of `final`.

Comment: This didn't work but I understand what you are saying and value your input. I believe the problem is that I am calling concatAll recursively but final is reset each time.. does this reset that last 'iteration' of concatAll's final?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I needed final += in front of the recursive call for when it comes back up the tree.

```
def concatAll
 final = ""

 if @lchild.respond_to?('string')   
    final += @lchild.to_s
 else
   final += @lchild.concatAll unless @lchild.nil?
 end

 if @rchild.respond_to?('string')   
   final +=  @rchild.to_s
 else
   final += @rchild.concatAll unless @rchild.nil?
 end

 final
end
```

Special thanks to Mark Thomas